# Grails find in relationship

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm breaking my head into wall about this logic, I have 2 domains, User and RSS. When the user add a RSS, I have to compare if it's not duplicated URL in my db by given another URL in the same user.

```
class RSS {
    Long id
    String link
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}

class User {
    Long id
    Long uid //facebook
    String name
    static hasMany = [rss:RSS]
}

def addRSS(){
//logic url is valid or not
...
 def user = User.findByUid(data.id) //get User uid and then by this uid, i can get the all RSS url
 //and compare like if(db_url == given_url) ...
}
```

I tried many ways and I had no success.

Comment: didn't understand almost a word, other than banging your head :) can you describe your problem in a more appropriate way? what should be  the result you want?

Comment: Before saving into db, first i need compare the 2 urls, one in db vs other given by user, if already exists in db, dont save, if not, save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use one of the [`findOrSaveWhere`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveWhere.html) or [`findOrCreateWhere`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrCreateWhere.html) methods

```
def url = 'some url from user' //data.url I would assume
def user = User.findByUid(data.id)
RSS.findOrSaveWhere(url: url, user: user)
```

If it's in the db it will fetch it for you if not it will create it for you.  The documentation explains the difference between the `*Save*` and `*Create*`

Comment: Yes, that was I'm looking for! Didn't know that exists.

Answer (score 0):

Simple join would do I think:

```
def existing = RSS.withCriteria{
  eq 'link', url
  eq 'user.id', userId
}
```

or

```
def existing = RSS.withCriteria{
  eq 'link', url
  user{ eq 'uid', uidd }
}

if( existing ) return
else doSave()
```